# Scroll issue on .animate() and .prop()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with same  class. If I scroll one div   the other divs scroll comes to 0. I am able to achieve this with .prop() property easily. But when I use .animate() the occurrence just happens once and then it stops working(Commented the code in my example snippet) . **What I want is the scroll when comes to zero should animate i.e the scroll  comes to 0 with a animation like its showing with .animate().**

> **Note: Classes of divs will be same and there can be more divs too.**

Here is the code I have tried, please tell me where I am wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.swipe_div').scroll(function() {


    // $(this).siblings(".swipe_div").animate({scrollLeft: 0},100);
    $(this).siblings(".swipe_div").prop({
      scrollLeft: 0
    });

  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swipe_div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

.content,
.operation,
.swipe_container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.swipe_container {
  width: 150%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30pt;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.operation {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: anyone having any clue ? :/

Comment: scroll event is  triggering every time when you move scroll

Comment: @Afsar yes its working good with prop() but not with animate(). But in case with prop(). where it works good i want some animation too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're animating `scrollLeft` you're activating `scroll()` on the sibling, which is trying to animate scroll on the div you're actively scrolling. So you need to mark when you start scrolling and `throttle()` all subsequent calls on `scroll()` until you're done scrolling.

`trailing:true` calls it one more time after it hasn't been called for  *throttle_interval* (`250` in this example), turning `scrolling` marker back to `false`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrolling;
  $('.swipe_div').scroll(_.throttle(function() {
    if (!scrolling) {
      scrolling = true;
      $(this).siblings(".swipe_div").animate({scrollLeft: 0},150);
    } else {
      scrolling = false;
    }
  }, 250, {leading:true,trailing:true}));
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swipe_div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

.content,
.operation,
.swipe_container {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.swipe_container {
  width: 150%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30pt;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.operation {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="swipe_div">
  <div class="swipe_container">
    <div class="content">
      &#x3e;
    </div>
    <div class="operation">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tested it for a bit and actually discovered a small glitch/limitation: the throttle interval has to be smaller than the animation time. If it is not, the animation will outlast the throttle interval and trigger, in turn, the closing animation for the original scrolled element.

But this is web (impossible is nothing): if and when your animation has to be longer than the throttle interval, you will have to mark the initial element with a class that will exclude it from being animated. The class will be removed using a timeout on completion of animate, equal to the throttle interval:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrolling;
  $('.swipe_div').scroll(_.throttle(function() {
    if (!scrolling) {
      scrolling = true;
      $(this).addClass('original');
      $(this).siblings(".swipe_div:not(.original)").animate(
        {scrollLeft:0},
        250,
        function(){
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.swipe_div').removeClass('original')
          }, 150)
        }
      );
    } else {
      scrolling = false;
    }
  }, 150, {leading:true,trailing:true}));
});
```